# Can I use url search params inside amp-script?

Tags: amp-html

It would be great if I could use url search params inside `<amp-script>`. I am not using amp only due to this restriction, for now. Is it by any chance possible to use url search params inside `<amp-script>`?

Amp can, already, [manipulate url search params](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md). I only need the "last mile" of connecting those url search params to my `<amp-script>`. Is it possible?

Comment: To which DOM element do you plan to bind?

Comment: Can you please file a feature request here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A+Feature+Request&template=feature_request.md&title=

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want to access `location.href`, or another property of the `location` object?

If so, there's [an open issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/26791) for that. I'd encourage you to comment there and explain your use case. Or, better still, AMP is an open-source project, as is [WorkerDOM](https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom), which `<amp-script>` is based on. Suggest this and submit a PR!

Comment: It may be possible to do today in a _very_ hacky way by using the `AMPDOC_URL` URL substitution that is sent in the `src` to an `amp-state` which will then echo back the actual value in the JSON response, and then to read that `amp-state` in `amp-script`! Gross!! But it may work. Not recommended though.

Comment: Weston, that's pretty ingenious ;)