# Get window URL in AMP

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html, ampscript

I have been trying to use the window.location.search inside my custom javascript to get the page URL in AMP page but I am getting empty field.
Is there any way/function by which I can get the page URL?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain AMP's performance guarantees, custom JS code runs in a Web Worker, and certain restrictions apply. So you can't act on elements that are outside of the `<amp-script>` component (Web Worker). In other words, it's virtual DOM. [Documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) for `<amp-script>` component.

Here is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107653/can-i-use-url-search-params-inside-amp-script/63179459). Also check these [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107653/can-i-use-url-search-params-inside-amp-script/63179459#comment114030794_63179459) posted by @Weston Ruter, that might be a solution for your problem.

*Alternatively you can try using PHP instead.*